# Symfony2 application not working when moving vendor directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have installed OroCommerce, a Symfony2 based application. I want to have the 'vendor' directory on a higher level outside the users directory. I followed the steps at http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-vendor-directory but now the namespaces can't be found. I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 399: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "framework" (in /home/oro2/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for namespace "framework", found "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution", "debug"
>       in YamlFileLoader.php line 399
>       at YamlFileLoader->validate(array('imports' => array(array('resource' => 'config.yml')), 'framework' => array('router' => array('resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml'), 'profiler' => array('only_exceptions' => false)), 'web_profiler' => array('toolbar' => true, 'intercept_redirects' => false), 'monolog' => array('handlers' => array('main' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path' => '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'))), 'oro_assetic' => array('css_debug' => null, 'css_debug_all' => false), 'oro_message_queue' => array('client' => array('traceable_producer' => true))), '/home/oro2/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 369
>       at YamlFileLoader->loadFile('/home/oro2/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 44
>       at YamlFileLoader->load('/home/oro2/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml', null) in DelegatingLoader.php line 45
>       at DelegatingLoader->load('/home/oro2/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml') in AppKernel.php line 35
>       at AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration(object(DelegatingLoader)) in bootstrap.php.cache line 2776
>       at Kernel->buildContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2728
>       at Kernel->initializeContainer() in OroKernel.php line 290
>       at OroKernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2507
>       at Kernel->boot() in OroKernel.php line 252
>       at OroKernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2538
>       at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 33

Am I forgetting something? Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhere calling `%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml` which actually does not exist, because you have moved the config file dir

Comment: I see what you mean. I now hardcoded the path to file but the same error exists.

Comment: Can change it but it doesn't solve the initial problem.